# .NET Network tracing only for Debug builds

Tags: .net, trace

I have enabled .NET network tracing per this article here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

Unfortunately, the log files are generated for both Release and Debug builds even though TRACE is not enabled for my Release build.

I'm trying to find a way to leave the logging enabled for the Debug build and disabled for the Retail build but I am at a loss for how to do this. I have tried all sorts of things and none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.